# Telnetting the Local port not working but trying the ip working

Tags: telnet

My application listens on port 8180.

When I am trying to connect to port 8180 locally.
Connection got refused.
But when I am trying to connect to port with ip . I am able to connect.

```
[root@MUMLGOMAPP002 ~]# telnet 10.209.129.54 8180
Trying 10.209.129.54...
Connected to MUMLGOMAPP002 (10.209.129.54).
Escape character is '^]'.
^]
telnet> q
Connection closed.


[root@MUMLGOMAPP002 ~]# telnet localhost 8180
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

My interface is :

```
[root@MUMLGOMAPP002 ~]# ifconfig
bond0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 44:1E:A1:73:F7:50
          inet addr:10.209.129.54  Bcast:10.209.129.63  Mask:255.255.255.224
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MASTER MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:322997568 errors:23 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:304470664 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:213628580915 (198.9 GiB)  TX bytes:217449664400 (202.5 GiB)
```

I would like to know what is the difference between telnetting localhost and ip.

Answer (score 3):

A network process can either `bind` to a specific address, or any address.

To see which yours is doing, try `lsof -n -i TCP:8180 -s TCP:LISTEN`.

You should see either:

```
COMMAND   PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
[lots of other stuff...............................] 10.209.129.54:8180 (LISTEN)
```

or

```
COMMAND   PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
[lots of other stuff...............................] *:8180 (LISTEN)
```

The first one tells you that your process bound to that specific IP address, and is what I think you will see.

When you do `telnet localhost 8180`, `telnet` resolves the hostname to an IP address.  It should resolve to `127.0.0.1`.  So your system tries to connect to `127.0.0.1:8180`.  If your server is only listening on `10.209.129.54:8180`, the networking layer will refuse the connection to `127.0.0.1:8180`.

If you need to make both work, it will depend on what server program you're using.

In case you're talking about JBoss, which seems to commonly use port 8180, see https://developer.jboss.org/thread/168789 for how you could make both work.  Note that doing so might cause confusion if you're running multiple JBoss servers on the same host.