# Telnetting the local port working but trying with ip not working

Tags: ip, hostname, hosts, telnet, connection-sharing

My question is similar but opposite to to [Telnetting the Local port not working but trying the ip working](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209423/telnetting-the-local-port-not-working-but-trying-the-ip-working)

For me, `telnet` to the local port works but trying with IP does not work :(

I am running `pgbouncer` on port 6432:

```
$ telnet 192.x.x.x 6432
Trying 192.x.x.x...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

I set `listen_addr = *`, but still using `telnet` with IP from another server is not working.

See http://lists.pgfoundry.org/pipermail/pgbouncer-general/2013-January/001097.html for the same scenario (but no useful answer).

The output of `netstat -plnt` is

```
 tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:6432 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 19879/./pgbouncer
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: @DopeGhoti:   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6432              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      19879/./pgbouncer


I tried listen_addr = * , listen_addr = 192.x.x.x & listen_addr = 127.0.0.1
But not working in any case

Note: I am trying to connect telnet from another server

Comment: @roaima - ah I see what you're talking about in taking a 2nd look at your answer, will undup it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick Google shows that recommended safe configurations for `pgbouncer` often set up the listening port only on the loopback interface (`localhost`). [Here is one example](http://michael.otacoo.com/postgresql-2/first-steps-with-pgbouncer-how-to-set-and-run-it/):

```
[pgbouncer]
listen_port = 5433
listen_addr = localhost
auth_type = any
logfile = pgbouncer.log
pidfile = pgbouncer.pid
```

The [configuration documentation](https://pgbouncer.github.io/config.html) explains clearly how to change the addresses on which the service listens:

> **listen_addr**
>
> Specifies list of addresses, where to listen for TCP connections. You
>   may also use * meaning “listen on all addresses”. When not set, only
>   Unix socket connections are allowed.
>
> Addresses can be specified numerically (IPv4/IPv6) or by name.
>
> Default: not set
>
> **listen_port**
>
> Which port to listen on. Applies to both TCP and Unix sockets.
>
> Default: 6432

Since you've now responded that you've already done this, I'll leave it here for the record, but make an additional suggestion below.

---

The follow-up posts on the mailing list to [the one you referenced](http://lists.pgfoundry.org/pipermail/pgbouncer-general/2013-January/001097.html) provide [the answer](http://lists.pgfoundry.org/pipermail/pgbouncer-general/2013-January/001098.html). I'll quote it here:

> **User 1**
>
> I restarted using `/etc/init.d/pgbouncer restart`, which effectively
>   launches `pgbouncer` with `-R` for a online restart.
>
> **User 2**
>
> I suspect the `-R` is working too well for you - it reuses the old
>   listening socket, with means the bind address stays the same.
>
> This preference is natural - you rarely change bind addres, but may
>   change other settings (or `pgbouncer` version).
>
> **You should just do proper stop/start**, then it should take new address in use.

Comment: I set listen_addr as "*" , but still telnetting with IP from another server not working.  Refer http://lists.pgfoundry.org/pipermail/pgbouncer-general/2013-January/001097.html

Comment: @Raja please include this information in your question for others to see. It's important!

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Yes, For  restart pgbouncer, i used **./pgbouncer -R -d etc/pgbouncer.ini**.
Now I killed that process & start pgbouncer as **./pgbouncer -d etc/pgbouncer.ini**, Now working fine :) . One more small doubt, How to stop pgbouncer properly?

Comment: @Raja `service pgbouncer stop` would be my starting point.